# Percents of Random Samples

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, uncertainty, stratification

I have three sets $A,B,C$ of sizes $N_A=2508$, $N_B=36211$ and $N_C=2296$ respectively, containing binary values. I took 200 samples of each set to produce point estimates of the averages: $\hat p_A=0.245$, $\hat p_B=0.04$, $\hat p_C=0.035$. I approximated the respective standard deviations using the usual proportion standard deviation formula with finite population correction.

I am interested in the percent of ones in each distribution relative to the total number of ones in all distributions. For instance, an estimate of the proportion of ones that exist in population $A$ relative to all distributions is
$$\frac{N_A\hat p_A}{N_A\hat p_A+N_B\hat p_B+N_C\hat p_C}\times 100\% = 28.7\%$$

(Note that I have found multiple ones in each set, so the percent is well-defined.)

I want to quantify the uncertainty of this percent. I have tried using standard "propagation of error" formulas for computing standard deviation under addition and division (apparently corresponding to the formulas from addition and division of normal variables), but these don't take into account that the term on the numerator ($N_a\hat p_A$ in the example above) appears in the denominator. To illustrate the issue, note that naive usage of the division formula would not conclude that $p_A/p_A$ is unity with a standard deviation of 0. Thus I am getting a wider standard deviation than necessary using this formula.

How could I quantify the uncertainty of the percent accurately?

Comment: Given that it is possible that all three proportions can be 0 ... the variance of the statistic will be undefined.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I have found at least one of each. It is a finite population, so there is no chance that it is zero.

Comment: Do you know the sizes of the populations?

Comment: @whuber I know both the population sizes and sample sizes.

Comment: Because it might matter, could you indicate how the sample sizes compare to the population sizes?  Rules of thumb suggest different approaches once at least one sample exceeds 5-10% of its population.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I updated the question with more details to faithfully match my real problem. One of the samples reaches nearly 9% of the population.

Comment: Your edit is extremely confusing: what do samples of populations $B$ and $C$ have to do with the properties of population $A$?  On the face of it, absolutely nothing.  Why, then, do you construct "an estimate of the proportion of ones that exist in population $A$" from those samples?  Why doesn't $\hat p_A$ give you that estimate already?  It looks like you instead are trying to estimate what fraction of *all ones in all three populations* are in population $A.$  May we assume all three populations are disjoint or not?

Comment: @whuber They are independent completely, since in each set an instance of a 1 represents something else. 

I suppose my phrasing wasn't clear; what I want is the number of ones in A relative to the total number of ones present in all sets together as the formula describes. Updated accordingly.